# Обновить данные для дубликатов

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Есть таблица заказов, в ней имеются дублирующиеся заказы

orders

uuid | user_uuid | product_uuid | created_at | status

Есть статусы 5 - archived и 6 - cancelled

Суть в чем - надо обновить все дубликаты, переместив в cancelled все дублирующиеся заказы кроме самого нового

Пробовал сделать так

```
 update orders o
 join
 (
     select user_uuid, product_uuid, max(created_at) date, count(*) count
     from orders
     where user_uuid is not null and status_id not in (5, 6)
     group by user_uuid, product_uuid
     having count > 1
 ) dup
 on o.user_uuid = dup.user_uuid
 and o.product_uuid = dup.product_uuid
 and o.created_at != dup.date
set status_id = 6
where o.uuid is not null;
```

Но есть проблема - у некоторых заказов даты идентичны и в таком случае такие заказы не обновляются. Может у кого есть мысль как это дело можно обновить чтобы заработало?

Comment: *надо обновить все дубликаты, переместив в cancelled все дублирующиеся заказы кроме самого нового* Из этой фразы выходит, что надо определить самый новый. *у некоторых заказов даты идентичны* А эта фраза утверждает, что определить самый новый только на основании даты - невозможно. Вывод: придумывайте критерий, позволяющий всё же определить, какая запись - самая "новая".

Comment: `created_at` - имеет тип DATE? да ещё небось присваивается не автоматически, а приложением? Переделывайте этот [censored] срочно, если ещё возможно, конечно.

Comment: В случае с одинаковыми датами нам не принципиально какой считать самым новым, можно просто брать на основании order by created_at desc первый в выдаче, но я если честно уже подзапутался и не совсем понимаю куда дальше копать

Comment: Как раз и переделываем, но надо сначала бардак в базе прибрать

Comment: "Непринципиально" - это под пиво на лавочке сойдёт. А как критерий выбора - нет. *можно просто брать на основании order by created_at desc первый в выдаче* Понятие "первый" появляется только тогда, когда определена сортировка, при которой каждая запись уникальна. У тебя это не выполняется - значит, понятия "первый" не существует. А что там рисуется на клиенте, сервер не в курсе...

Comment: *Как раз и переделываем, но надо сначала бардак в базе прибрать* Сначала надо переделать. Например, сделать это поле datetime, добавить в него компоненту времени (например, используя ROW_NUMBER()), а потом убирать хлам. Вот если бы ты сжимал (datetime -> date), тогда да, надо было бы начинать с чистки.

Comment: так у нас и так datetime, я если честно не совсем понимаю откуда там есть время идентичное до миллисекунды, но работаем с чем есть в дампе с прода. На уровне прилаги докинули запрет добавлять дубликаты заказов, но вот это барахло осталось. По поводу "непринципиально" это буквально бизнес требование, важно только чтобы остался один заказ для одного юзера на один продукт

Comment: Будь моя воля - почистил бы уже руками, насчет что хорошо и что плохо тоже можно не расписывать, сам понимаю, пришел сюда ибо есть проблема, есть какое-то решение, но оно не совсем применимо в моей ситуации, я в рамках своих полномочий не могу влиять на бизнес требования, мне описана проблема, надо решать, может есть какая идея? Решение не прошу, просто направление куда смотреть

Comment: В таком случае рекомендую скопировать данные в другую таблицу с удалением дубликатов `INSERT INTO copy SELECT DISTINCT * FROM main`, а потом очистить рабочую таблицу и вернуть данные. Ибо, как я понимаю, обсуждаемые записи являются полными дубликатами. Ну а затем уже удалять частичные дубликаты, ибо появится критерий уникальной сортировки.

Comment: о, идея огонь, спасибо

Comment: Ну или такой вариант. Добавить вспомогательное поле, заполнить его последовательными числами (ROW_NUMBER) от фонаря, удалить дубли, используя это поле как дополнительный критерий сортировки, а затем удалить поле.

Comment: а как это можно провернуть? ну я о примерном виде запроса с сортировкой по этому полю

Comment: Вот так: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ac6053eb752cc4960b28164aa11e02a6

Comment: то что надо, огромный респект, можешь ответом оформить - дам плюсик в карму)

Comment: Лень... много доделывать, чтобы ответ стал полезным и понятным. Если есть желание - можешь сам сделать самоответ.

Comment: хорошо, реально выручил, спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помощь от [Akina](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/229437/akina):

1. Добавляем временное int поле в таблицу
2. Записываем значения от 1 до n
3. Используем это поле как дополнительный критерий сортировки

Пример: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ac6053eb752cc4960b28164aa11e02a6